# flex several httpservice on a form

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I need to load a form where data load come from several mySQL table.
My question is how to load this request in the same php file or is the best way is to execute several http service to load data.
Thanks for helping

Comment: In this case its better to use the RemoteObject with single php file consist of various functions to load the data.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with more queries in one php file, than return all result to one httpservice. Later you put result data to form.

Or, call httpservice two or more times with different url:

url="file.php?do=query1"

url="file.php?do=query2"

and use [AsynToken](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Tracking_results_from_multiple_simultaneous_servic-922.html) to handle result for each call.